# What does this symbol on the EV3 Brick mean?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

I can’t figure out how to get my R3PTAR to open and close it’s mouth to bite. I keep getting this symbol. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You either have to recharge your battery (if you're using a battery pack) or replace the batteries (if you're using normal batteries). If this symptom persists after charging the battery pack, try to do a master reset on the brick. Failing which, you might have to replace the battery pack.

Answer (score 0):

It's a symbol for low battery power.  You have to recharge the brick.

[image]

How long?  Check out *[Mr. Hino's YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LAsQT7MJ7k)* on how long it took to juice his back up.

For a full recharge, we're waiting for the red brick light to turn off...

[image]

[image]

[image]